# Maximum tag name length?

Tags: support, tags

Does a maximum tag name length exist? Or it is just the "suggested size" with no hard limits? I'm trying to figure out how to best store them in a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags on the sites are, at most, 35 characters.

Permitted characters are `a-z 0-9 + # - .`

However, this is not part of the API contract insofar as if the *site* definition of a tag changes so will the API's.  It is advisable, for correctness, to have a code path to handle tags > 35 characters in length.  Simplest would be to truncate them.